# What are the odds of a repeat in numpy.random.rand(n) (assuming perfect randomness)?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, probability, ieee-754

For the moment, put aside any issues relating to pseudorandom number generators and assume that [`numpy.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) perfectly samples from the discrete distribution of floating point numbers over `[0, 1)`. What are the odds getting at least two exactly identical floating point numbers in the result of:

```
numpy.random.rand(n)
```

for any given value of `n`?

Mathematically, I think this is equivalent to first asking how many [IEEE 754 singles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) or [doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) there are in the interval `[0, 1)`. Then I guess the next step would be to solve the equivalent [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)? I'm not really sure. Anyone have some insight?

Comment: I feel like this should belong in https://math.stackexchange.com/... how is this information relevant anyhow?

Comment: Afraid of a little math? The default assumption seems to be that it's straight impossible for this kind of collision to occur. I for one would like an actual number attached to that blind assumption. This involves a bunch of domain specific knowledge, so at least the first part (count of floats `[0, 1)`) definitely belongs here.

Comment: Not really, the whole problem basically boils down to given `n` number of random floating points, what are the odds of there being at least one identical pair? All you need to know is the implementation details of the floating points (e.g. how many digits) and any mathematician can work it out.  I just don't see how finding out the odds adds to the discussion in Stackoverflow (which is mostly for debugging questions).

Comment: "assume that numpy.random.rand perfectly samples from the uniform distribution over [0, 1)" - 0, because that assumption is too strong.

Comment: It's a hypothetical question. Of course it's not realistic. Of course the period of any PRNG is going to be shorter than the count of all floats. That's why I made the assumption explicit in both the title and the first sentence.

Comment: Perfectly sampling from the uniform distribution over [0, 1) would require infinite-precision arithmetic, and would produce a probablity of 0 for repeats. Even assuming a perfect randomness source, you need to consider the details of how `numpy.random.rand` uses the randomness source to produce doubles.

Comment: (And yes, the details do matter. Get them wrong, and you get the wrong probability. For example, the algorithm used by `numpy.random.rand` cannot actually produce most doubles between 0 and 1.)

Comment: I clarified the intended discrete distribution in the first sentence. "`numpy.random.rand` cannot actually produce most doubles between 0 and 1". That's just the kind of low-level detail that I was hoping would come up when I wrote this question. It would be great if you added an answer with the details.

Comment: @tel The "default assumption" you mention is definitely wrong; I'd be interested to know where you've seen it. The result of `np.random.rand(120*10**6)` is more likely to have repeats than not; this is easy to verify experimentally at a prompt by running `len(np.unique(np.random.rand(120*10**6)))` a few times. (It takes a few seconds per run.)

Comment: @Idlehands: Stack Overflow is not mostly for debugging questions. [It is for programming problems, algorithms, software tools, and other problems unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That includes problems designing and proving algorithms, including calculations about frequencies with which problematic duplications might occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computation performed by `numpy.random.rand` for each element generates a number `0.<53 random bits>`, for a total of 2^53 equally likely outputs. (Of course, the memory representation isn't a fixed-point `0.stuff`; it's still floating point.) This computation is incapable of producing most binary64 floating-point numbers between 0 and 1; for example, it cannot produce 1/2^60. You can see the code in [`numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.4/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L515):

```
double
rk_double(rk_state *state)
{
    /* shifts : 67108864 = 0x4000000, 9007199254740992 = 0x20000000000000 */
    long a = rk_random(state) >> 5, b = rk_random(state) >> 6;
    return (a * 67108864.0 + b) / 9007199254740992.0;
}
```

(Note that `rk_random` produces 32-bit outputs, regardless of the size of `long`.)

Assuming a perfect source of randomness, the probability of repeats in `numpy.random.rand(n)` is 1-(1-0/k)(1-1/k)(1-2/k)...(1-(n-1)/k), where k=2^53. It's probably best to use an [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations) instead of calculating this directly for large values of n. (The approximation may even be more accurate, depending on how the approximation error compares to the rounding error accumulated in a direct computation.)

Comment: Looks more like the probability of no repeats to me.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Whoops, you're right. I forgot to invert it. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct, this is like the birthday problem.
But you need to decide on the number of possible options. You do this by deciding the precision of your floating point numbers.
For example, if you decide to have a precision of 2 numbers after the dot, then there are 100 options(including zero and excluding 1).

And if you have n numbers then the probability of not having a collision is:

[image]

or when given R possible numbers and N data points, the probability of no collision is:

[image]

And of collision is 1 - P.

This is because the probability of getting any given number is 1/R. And at any point, the probability of a data point not colliding with prior data points is (R-i)/R for i being the index of the data point. But to get the probability of no data points colliding with each other, we need to multiply all the probabilities of data points not colliding with those prior to them. Applying some algebraic operations, we get the equation above.

[image: (I would have written some equation in LaTex but it seems there is no option to do that here)]

Comment: I think your answer's right, but it's about [fixed point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). I want to know the answer for the IEEE 754 floating point numbers that people actually use most of the time in code (single or double would be fine).

Comment: The usual workaround for the lack of latex support is to format your equation as an image (you can use this online [widget here](https://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) for that) and then copy/paste the image into your answer (once an image is in your clipboard, you can just edit your question and do `ctrl-v` to dump the image into the text).

Comment: IEEE 754 singles have 23 fraction bits and the exponent is usually unsigned. S there are 2^23 possible different fractions between 0 and 1. Thus, the R value you plug into the equation is 2^23. For IEEE 754 doubles, there are 52 fraction bits.

Comment: Looking at the [numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy), a uniform double in [0, 1) is generated by dividing a uniform 53-bit value by 2^53. These are all exactly representable, so there are exactly 2^53 values.

Comment: You are correct. Somehow I missed the part where the Wiki page explains that unsigned exponents have a bias of -127. In that case, there are really 2^30 possible different representable fractions.

Comment: @ShayLempert: It is voted down because the business about “deciding the precision” and “2 numbers after the dot” is nonsense. Two numbers are different if they are not equal. The question explicitly asks about “two exactly identical floating point numbers.”

Comment: @Eric Postpischil.The answer is general, It gives you an equation for any number of possible different choices. And I gave "2 numbers after the dot"(in decimal base) as an example. I should fix "numbers" to "digits"(English isn't my native language so mistakes happen). But other than that, I don't see how it's not relevant to the question. You literally just have to plug in the equation R=2^30 and your N of choice.

Comment: @ShayLempert: “2 numbers after the dot” is nonsense not because it is “numbers” rather than “digits” but because **binary** floating-point does not have **decimal** digits after the point. Floating-point objects represent abstract numbers. They should not be conflated with decimal representations or approximations. Even if you were combining different floating-point numbers into two-decimal-digit bins, the resulting distribution would be non-uniform, so the formula no longer applies.

Comment: And no, you do not plug in R=2^30 (or 127•2^23). The number of **representable** `float` values is irrelevant; the proper number is the number of **values `numpy` `rand` may return**. The other answerer went to the trouble of examining the `numpy` source code and finding the correct answer: 2^53.

Comment: [Edited to correct.] The number of IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point numbers in [0, 1) is not 2^23. It is 127•2^23. 2^23 is the number of numbers with a particular exponent value. But all the numbers for every exponent from −126 to −1, inclusive, are in [0, 1). In addition, zero and the subnormal numbers are in [0, 1), and there are 2^23 of them. So that is 2^23 times 127. Another way of counting is that the encoding for 1 is 0x3f800000 (0 sign bit, 127 exponent code, 0 significand), and the encodings are in ascending order for positive numbers, so all codes from 0 to that are in [0, 1).